# How do I partition an external drive on macOS 13.2.1?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

I have an external drive and I am running macOS 13.2.1. I'd like to partition the external drive into two partitions and use one of those for a Time Machine backup. In Disk Utility, it has the +|- Volume button greyed out :

[image: Screenshot (on macOS) of Disk Utility showing a 1TB USB external disk named "stuff" almost completely empty. Shows also the +|- Volume button as well as the Partition button greyed out.]

I've read [here](https://www.macgasm.net/news/partition-greyed-out-mac/) that this is only available for APFS partitions.  When I try to erase it, I only get the options : "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled", "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)", "MS-DOS (FAT)", "ExFAT"

Question :

- How do I do partition this external hard drive?

**NOTE**

This is not a duplicate of the [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58468) question.  That question is 11 years old, way before the APFS was introduced and the answers in that question do not answer the question for OSX 13.2.1.  The interface for Disk Utility has changed a bit in the last 11 years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to partition External HD for both Time Machine and other purposes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58468/how-to-partition-external-hd-for-both-time-machine-and-other-purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may have two separate issues here…

The first is easy - Press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>  or from the View menu, choose Show All Devices.
This will let you see the actual root device of each volume hierarchically.

The second issue, I suspect, and which will be revealed after the first is 'fixed' is that though you have an HFS+ partition, it's sitting on an underlying Master Boot Record [MBR] scheme. It should be on GUID.

The telltales are that it doesn't show an APFS option if you try to format - APFS *must* be on GUID, and that it gives no option to further partition - again an MBR/GUID issue.

You can't directly see past these as clues unless you can also see the Device data
<sub>Don't worry that this is just an SD card, the other information will be the same</sub>

MBR/HFS+
[image]

Again, MBR/HFS+ Device view…
[image]

and GUID/HFS+ Device view
[image]

See how we now have Partition options [you can also now use APFS].
The Volume +/- button comes once you have APFS, along with the Container structure.

[image]

*BTW, don't use case-sensitive unless you know **why** you might need to.*

Comment: Great, thanks.  With CMD + 2, I see the top level device. If I "Erase" it, it gives me the options of "Master Boot Record", "GUID Partition Map" and "Apple Partition Map".  It is scary to reformat the "Master Boot Record" because the name makes me think that I'll brick this device.  If I reformat it to GUID Partition Map, my computer should still be able to connect to it, correct?

Comment: It will be perfectly capable of reading any format it can write; but only GUID/APFS will let you set it up for Time Machine on Ventura. Formatting to *anything* will of course erase any data already on the drive, so copy off first. Drive manufacturers ship drives MBR/ExFAT because all OSes can read & write to that, but it's **no** OS's 'favourite' format.